# Having a simple rig, ¿why mining ETH is not the best way to get ETH?

Tags: mining, gpu

What are the factors that affect the profitability of mining different coins when later those coins are being converted, for example, to ETH?

I've made some test mining ETH, RVN, CFX, AE, BEAM, GRIN, and some other. All of them for the same period of time, let's say 1 hour, some of them on different pools, always with the same rig (1 RTX 2070 S).

Then I converted all those coins to ETH. Each coin gives a different amount of ETH, making one or the other more proffitable in order to get ETH. In this case in particular, ETH is not the best choice in order to get ETH if you have a simple rig. So it seems that it is better to mine something else and then do the exchange.

Now about the factors, I guess it could be the difficulty of the pool / network, the hash minimum target, the amount of people mining and what percentage / power do I give to that pool? Consider all the exchanges and calculations have been made the same day or that the price itself (in USD or ETH) was not a relevant factor.

I remark the fact that the rig is very simple, I guess with a better rig you'll be better prepared and mining ETH would be the best choice in order to get ETH.

Answer (score 0):

Original question :"What are the factors that affect the profitability of mining different coins when later those coins are being converted, for example, to ETH?"

some of the factors are:

How many people are exchanging it for etherum. If nobody is exchanging bitcoin for etherum 1 bitcoin wont be worth much ETHER.

How esay is it to get that coin. If u can mine 100 X  coins in 1 second it wouldnt be much ether for 100x coins bc how is it is.

diffeculty of the pool or network: Like you said. read ^^^^^.

Hope it helped.